# Add property dynamically to class based on DeserializeXml result fields

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have sample classes

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Profiles")]
public class Profiles : List<ProfileSearch> { }

[XmlType(TypeName = "Profile")]
public class ProfileSearch {
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public AdditionalData AdditionalData { get; set; }
}

public class AdditionalData {
    public int UniqueId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string LocalNumber { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I am deserializing the XML using the code below

```
var result = Common.Utilities.Serialization.DeserializeXml<Profiles>(XMLData);
```

Here XMLData is data in XML Format, this is provided by different clients.

Sometimes, XMLData contains new fields, which are not defined as properties in the AdditionalData class and these fields may be changed based on clients, so I cant add those fields as properties in the class

After deserializing the XMLData, these new fields data are missing.
So, I want to add those new fields dynamically based on XMLData to class as properties, so that I can't miss those fields data to display.

below are the sample XMLData values

Data1

```
<Profiles>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>1</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company1</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>12455</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample1@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>1123455678</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title1</Title>
        <Fr_Feminine>data1</Fr_Feminine>
        <Fr_Masculine>data2</Fr_Masculine>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>2</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company2</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>12435</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample2@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>435454454</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title2</Title>
        <Fr_Feminine>data21</Fr_Feminine>
        <Fr_Masculine>data22</Fr_Masculine>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>3</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company3</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>23421</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample3@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>343554545</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title3</Title>
        <Fr_Feminine>data31</Fr_Feminine>
        <Fr_Masculine>data32</Fr_Masculine>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>4</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company4</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>34252</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample4@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>233434535</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title4</Title>
        <Fr_Feminine>data41</Fr_Feminine>
        <Fr_Masculine>data42</Fr_Masculine>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
```

Data 2

```
<Profiles>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>1</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company1</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>12455</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample1@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>1123455678</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title1</Title>
        <Designation>Designation1</Designation>
        <Address>Address1</Address>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>2</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company2</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>12435</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample2@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>435454454</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title2</Title>
        <Designation>Designation2</Designation>
        <Address>Address2</Address>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>3</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company3</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>23421</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample3@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>343554545</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title3</Title>
        <Designation>Designation1</Designation>
        <Address>Address3</Address>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
<Profile>
    <ProfileId>4</ProfileId>
    <Company>Company4</Company>
    <AdditionalData>
        <UniqueId>34252</UniqueId>
        <Email>sample4@abc.com</Email>
        <LocalNumber>233434535</LocalNumber>
        <Title>Sample Title4</Title>
        <Designation>Designation2</Designation>
        <Address>Address4</Address>
    </AdditionalData>
</Profile>
```

Profiles end tag added but not displaying, so please add end tags for Profiles while using this XML data

Comment: So imagine you deserialize this stuff and add a new property to your class (if you could). What will the rest of your code do with it? First, you'll have to guess the name of the property I plan on adding to the XML next week -- but I haven't decided yet what it's going to be.

Comment: As far as i can see, you have two options: have objects for each xml type or work with a XmlDocument to get those fields. Please share different xml inputs, someone may come up with more ideas.

Comment: You should implement you problem with a more dynamic solution. e.g: put all fields of the XML in a list of fields in the class, so code build on this can also read the fields dynamically....

Answer (score 0):

Use a dynamic solution like:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Profile")]
public class ProfileSearch {
    public int ProfileId { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public List<Field> AdditionalData { get; set; }
}

public class Field {
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    //More Properties Like DataType...
}
```

Of course this is not that easy to parse with a Standard XML parser, but for creating properties dynamically you would have to parse the XML anyway by yourselfe...